# A tag 'advogado-de-linguagem' seria considerada uma meta-tag?

Tags: debate, meta-tags

Fiz a pergunta [*É legal fazer 'delete this' em uma função membro?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6230/e-legal-fazer-delete-this-em-uma-funcao-membro) e adicionei a tag [advogado-de-linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advogado-de-linguagem). [Pouco depois](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4622) a tag foi removida por ser considerada uma meta-tag e não se ater a um assunto específico da pergunta.

No *SOen* a tag existe como [`language-lawyer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) e é descrita assim:

> Typical questions concern gaps between "what will usually work in practice" and "what the spec actually guarantees", but problems with understanding the structure of the spec are also on topic.

O principal objetivo dela é estabelecer que a pergunta se trata da especificação de uma linguagem e de como ela *deveria* funcionar em teoria. Não sobre como ela realmente funciona na prática e sobre o que as implementações fazem. Funciona como um indicativo de que tipo de resposta é esperada.

No [artigo do blog sobre as metas-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) é dado dois indicativos base:

> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the *only* tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the *only* tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
> 2. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices [to whom?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/04/best-practices-and-puffer-fish.html) Beginner [by what criteria?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/defending-perpetual-intermediacy.html) These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

De certa forma parece que a tag se encaixa no item 1. Ela é afinal uma meta-tag?

Comment: Advogado de linguagem jamais poderia ser a única tag de uma questão, pois você ainda precisa da tag da linguagem. Mesmo assim, acho a tag válida e não uma meta tag, quando você quiser esclarecer alguma parte mais complexa ou menos óbvia de uma linguagem (como por exemplo a palavra chave `checked` do C#).

Comment: Discussão relacionada sobre meta-tags: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/808/boas-praticas-e-meta-tags

Comment: Curioso, no SO a tag é usada majoritariamente para perguntas de C/C++. Nas primeiras páginas da lista, vi uma única pergunta de python.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que a tag [advogado-de-linguagem](/questions/tagged/advogado-de-linguagem) devia ser mantida. Ela poderia indicar quando alguém usa uma opinião como um argumento de força, e relacionar meta questões que tratem sobre isso.